# Can I construct composed classes without using 'new' so much?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, composition

I have a basic composition of types:

```
class A{
    public A(B1 b1, B2 b2){
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
    }
    public B1 b1 {get; private set;}
    public B2 b2 {get; private set;}
}

class B1{
    public B1(C1 c1, C2 c2, C3 c3){
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.c3 = c3;
    }
    public C1 c1 {get; private set;}
    public C2 c2 {get; private set;}
    public C3 c3 {get; private set;}
}
class B2{
    public B2(C1 c1, C2 c2, C3 c3){
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.c3 = c3;
    }
    public C1 c1 {get; private set;}
    public C2 c2 {get; private set;}
    public C3 c3 {get; private set;}
}

class C1{}
class C2{}
class C3{}
```

Is there a cleaner way to construct `A`?

```
public static void Main()
{
    A a = new A(new B1(new C1(), new C2(), new C3()), new B2(new C1(), new C2(), new C3()));
}
```

Can I achieve  the same construction without using `new` so much?
Is there something I can do to my constructors to make that possible?

Comment: What do the different `c1`, `c2`, `c3` represent?

Comment: Since it's all default constructors, give all the constructor parameters default values of `null` and do `this.c1 = c1 ?? new C1();`. But I have a feeling you are using default constructors to represent parameterized constructors, because.

Comment: You can internalize `new` into the constructor and set only the parameters you effectively need. Or you can use an IoC (if it makes sense) for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in the default constructor for `A` it created the new `B`'s and in the default constructor for `B` it created the C's you could simplify it to just `A a = new A();`

```
class A{
    public A() : this(new B1(), new B2())
    {
    }

    public A(B1 b1, B2 b2){
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
    }
    public B1 b1 {get; private set;}
    public B2 b2 {get; private set;}
}

class B1{
    public B1() : this(new C1(), new C2(), new C3())
    {
    }

    public B1(C1 c1, C2 c2, C3 c3){
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.c3 = c3;
    }
    public C1 c1 {get; private set;}
    public C2 c2 {get; private set;}
    public C3 c3 {get; private set;}
}
class B2{
    public B2() : this(new C1(), new C2(), new C3())
    {
    }

    public B2(C1 c1, C2 c2, C3 c3){
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.c3 = c3;
    }
    public C1 c1 {get; private set;}
    public C2 c2 {get; private set;}
    public C3 c3 {get; private set;}
}

class C1{}
class C2{}
class C3{}

public static void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to consider when composing types, especially if you want to avoid hard-coding `new` in order to attain better dependency injection, is to use a Dependency Container.

For example, using [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) you would do:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<A>();
builder.RegisterType<B1>();
builder.RegisterType<B2>();
builder.RegisterType<C1>();
builder.RegisterType<C2>();
builder.RegisterType<C3>();

var container = builder.Build();

var a = container.Resolve<A>();
```

This might seem like overkill for your simple example, but if you really are composing a complex object graph, then it's something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not a new keyword makes a new object what you can do is have optional parametars in constructor.

```
class A
{

//Proper Immutable property works only c# 6 
      public B1 B1 { get; }
      public B2 B2 { get; }
      public A(B1 b1 = null, B2 b2 = null)
      {
           B1 = b1??new B1();
           B2 = b2??new B2();
      }
}
```

but this makes little sense for immutable object and is better to just leave them null since it will just use memory for no reason.